# jQuery + CoffeeScript, slideToggle only hiding then showing again

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a FAQ page where a question turns to red when clicked and it's answer slides down, while all the other answers slide up. So at any one time only one answer is open, and only if open it's question will be highlighted red.

This is probably quite simple to achieve but I don't have much experience with javascript... So far everything is working fine if I click on different questions, but clicking on the same question while it is open will close it and then re-open it:

```
window.toggle_info = $ ->
  $('.toggle-button').click ->
    $('.toggle-button').removeClass("red-reply") unless $(this).hasClass('red')
    $('.toggle-info').slideUp("slow")
    $(this).next('.toggle-info').slideToggle("slow")
    $(this).toggleClass("red")
```

I've tried using `.not('red')`  `.not('.red')` `:not('red')` in various ways on the `$('.toggle-info').slideUp("slow")` line but it's not working.

The color toggle is working fine in all cases.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
$('.toggle-info').slideUp("slow")
$(this).next('.toggle-info').slideToggle("slow")
```

applies [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) to **all** of the `.toggle-info` elements including `$(this).next('.toggle-info')`. So you close them all and then `slideToggle` the `.toggle-info` the follows the `.toggle-button` that you just clicked. The `slideUp` will leave all of them closed and then the `slideToggle` will open the `.toggle-info` that you just closed.

If you wanted to be able to close a panel by click the `.toggle-button` of an open one, then you could do this:

```
$next = $(this).next('.toggle-info');
$('.toggle-info').not($next).slideUp("slow")
$next.slideToggle("slow")
```

The [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) call just removes `$next` from the elements that `slideUp` will be applied to. And if you wanted the `red` only on open `.toggle-button`s then you could do something like this:

```
$next = $(this).next('.toggle-info');
$('.toggle-info')
  .not($next)
  .slideUp("slow")
  .prev('.toggle-button')
  .removeClass('red');
$next.slideToggle("slow")
$(this).toggleClass("red")
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TEb2A/1/

I don't see anything that adds `.red-reply` so I've left out of the demo; presumably you have some code elsewhere that is doing things with that class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realized my mistake afterwards but wasn't adding the right code to fix it :) `.red-reply` was supposed to be just `.red`

Answer (score 0):

I mess with this script for ages but of course I get the answer 5 minutes after posting here :/

I changed it to `$(this).next('.toggle-info').slideToggle("slow") unless $(this).hasClass('red-reply')` and it works.

Still not sure why it wouldn't work before though...